My vs code keeps quitting automatically whenever i open it
My vs code keeps quitting automatically whenever i open it.I'm using a mac os big sur version 11.0.1, for 3 days now vs code quits the second after i open it,(it doesn't even get to load). I have tried reinstalling the latest vs code version but the same thing happened.Really confused why this is happening. Would deeply appreciate any help I can get here(started learning how to code 3 months ago).
I have tried reinstalling the latest vs code version but the same thing happened.

You need to [edit] your question and add more details. Try running it from a terminal to see if it prints any errors. Check for log files.

Welcome! Please copy and paste the output of the Help: About command (run in the command palette) into your question post. also check the output of code --disable-extensions --log trace and see if there are any messages that look related to the failure and add those messages to your question post in a code block.
